# Created remote server link to Azure, but dbo schema is not shown

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am developing a web application which in production connects to an Azure database but in my local environment connects to a SQL Server running in Docker. I would like my local database to link to the Azure database so that I can easily copy data from production. I was able to successfully link via these commands:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
  @server='remote',
  @srvproduct='',     
  @provider='sqlncli',
  @datasrc='mydb.database.windows.net',
  @location='',
  @provstr='',
  @catalog='mydb';

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
  @rmtsrvname = 'remote',
  @useself = 'false',
  @rmtuser = 'my_username',
  @rmtpassword = 'my_password';

EXEC sp_serveroption 'remote', 'rpc out', true;
```

...however although I can connect and am using the same username & password used by the app itself which works, I cannot see my objects in the `dbo` schema, only `sys` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Why am I unable to see `[remote].[mydb].[dbo].*` objects when linking to a remote Azure database? I get this error when attempting to SELECT:

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "remote" does not contain the table ""mydb"."dbo"."my_table"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Have you looked at the table's permissions?**

It appears to be a permissions problem. Your query is correct.

As a piece of advice, try connecting the server using a specific user who has been granted select permission on particular table/database.

```sql
GRANT select ON DATABASE::database_name TO username;
GO
```

Data from Azure sql database:

[image]

Output from Linked service:

[image]

Comment: Looks like my main issue was that I didn't run `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` to link the local user to the right remote user, so it was a permissions issue. Thanks for helping me find the answer.